# Spring Data Rest with url of format /foo/{id}/bar

Tags: java, rest, spring-data-rest

To conform to our internal standards, we have URLs that take the format

```
/RESOURCE/{id}/COMPONENT
```

trying to do something like

```
@RestResource(path = "/RESOURCE/{id}/COMPONENT")
public Optional<Resource> findById(long id);
```

doesn't work (it does accept requests at `/RESOURCE/{ID}` though). Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: do you mean `@RestResource(path = "/RESOURCE/{id}/COMPONENT")
public Optional<Resource> findById(@PathVariable("id") long id);`

Comment: Just tried adding that, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand from the [spring data rest documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/3.1.6.RELEASE/reference/html/#customizing-sdr.configuring-the-rest-url-path), it does not seem to possible.

You can do something like that call it `http://localhost:8080/users/search/RESOURCE?id=1`

```
@RestResource(path = "/RESOURCE")
public Optional<Resource> findById(@Param("id")long id);
```

However, if you will use URL like that `@RestResource(path = "/RESOURCE/{id}/COMPONENT")` and then it will return

```
{
"_links": {
    "findById": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/users/search/RESOURCE/%7Bid%7D/COMPONENT{?id}",
        "templated": true
    },
    "self": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/users/search"
    }
 }
}
```

As you can see from here, spring cannot resolve the URL and it gives invalid character problem. I can understand you are trying to use rest api design but it seems not possible for this situation.